# toggle body class when navbar collapse show class is added/removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

The are many ways to do this, but I want the best and cleanest method.

I want to toggle a custom `body` class when the `.navbar-toggle` toggles the `.show` class on the `.navbar-collapse` element.

I just think using another `on click` event on something that is already firing javascript seems a bit dirty. Is there anyway to bind to the existing functionally?

```
<body class="">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">#</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/s74x32uf/

Any ideas would be great thanks

Comment: *"The are many ways to do this"*  but which one are you using right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use [Bootstrap's collapse events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events)

**When the open animation is finished**

```
$('.navbar').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  alert('animation complete');
  $('body').addClass('your-class');
})
```

**When the closed animation is finished**

```
$('.navbar').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  alert('animation complete');
  $('body').addClass('your-class');
})
```

You can also add an event when the animation starts showing/hiding by using `show.bs.collapse` or `hide.bs.collapse`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s74x32uf/5/)

Comment: Hey thanks man i think wrote the question wrong. I want to be able to remove it when it closes too. Thanks

Comment: Ok. same logic just different event. Updated answer.